# ssis for each loop how to stop next iteration after failure

Tags: ssis, foreach-loop-container

Within a SSIS for each loop with default settings if a task fails it then fails the for each loop container which is required. However, the next iteration of the loop is still executed so it resets the vairables to new values. Rather than using store variables is there a way to prevent the next for each loop read.
Many Thanks

Comment: You could achieve same by setting a variable to false when you encounter the failure and check value of variable on next iteration. There is no 'Break' sort of functionality with 'Foreach Loop Container'.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Event Handler on  OnTaskFailed event by choosing right executable, define an variable and use this variable to store required value which can be used at next iteration.

[SSIS Event Handlers Basics](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/ssis/ssis-event-handlers-basics/)

[Integration Services (SSIS) Event Handlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140223.aspx)